# PHP: Display Column Names as Checkboxes, display as checked if column value is 1

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have the following table:

```
ID | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
25 | 1      |  0      |   0       |  1       | 1
```

(this doesn't format right, imagine a table with zeros if a day is unchecked and ones if a day is checked)

And I want it on my html page to display like this:

Monday (checked checkbox)
Tuesday (unchecked checkbox)
Wednesday (unchecked checkbox)

and so on.
I know that the input tag contains "checked" if you want the checkbox to be checked. but i need to insert an if condition into the input tag, that says if the $value is 1 then echo "checked". it is probably just a question of formatting the php inside the html inside the php correctly.

So far I have this PHP code, but it only gives me unchecked checkboxes without the day caption:

```
<html>    
<?php    
    $firstrow = false;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_skill)){
        if (!$firstrow) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='". $column . "' /><br>"; 
        }
        $firstrow = true;
        }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

What can I do?

Comment: Where did you expect to see the caption?

Comment: I haven't put the caption after the input tag yet, as I am not sure how to do it. The Caption is supposed to be the column name from my table.  ETA: the caption appears when I put the $column after the input tag. The main question is, how do I display the box as checked if the $value is 1?

Comment: Column name is stored in `$column` isn't it? Then what is the problem?

Comment: the caption appears when I put the $column after the input tag. The main question is, how do I display the box as checked if the $value is 1? it is probably just a question of getting all the ""s and '' s right.

Comment: Use `checked` attrubite for `input` tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be using is labels if you want to display captions for the checkboxes. value attribute is used while submitting a form to a page (in the form of name-value pairs). For keeping some day's checkbox ticked, you have to use checked attribute in checkbox element.

```
<?php    
   $firstrow = false;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_skill)){
     if (!$firstrow) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
           echo "<label for='".$column."ID'>".$column."</label>";
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' id='".$column."ID' value='". $column . "'";
           if($value==1){
              echo " checked='checked'";
           }
           echo "/><br>"; 
        }
        $firstrow = true;
     }
   }
?>
```

Using id attribute in input element and for attribute in label element isn't relevant to your problem. But it is a good programming practice to do so. I didn't get why were you using $firstrow, so I've kept that part of the code unchanged.

In place of `$value==1` you can use any other condition on which you want the checkbox to be checked by default.

Comment: I don't want to keep Monday checked by default, I want the Monday box to be checked if the value of the column for that specific ID is 1. For any other ID, it could be 0.

Comment: Here you go. I've added the changes